# TCP connection time in windows

Tags: windows, performance, networking, tcp, connection

I am doing some performance testing with a large number of threads.  Each thread is sending HTTP requests to another IP.  It looks like at some stages the connections are closed (because there are too many threads) and then of course have to be reopned.

I am looking to get some ball park figures for how long it takes windows to Open TCP connections.

Is there any way I can get this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly dependent on the endpoints you're trying to connect to, is it not?

As an extreme best case, you can test it yourself by targeting an IIS on localhost.

I wouldn't be surprised if routers and servers that you are connecting through may drop connections as a measure against what could be perceived as connection storms or even denial-of-service attacks.